# PHPUnit test dependencies

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

A similar question has been asked before but I don't quite understand the answer. My specific case is that I have a unit test which tests the registration of a user via a REST API endpoint. User registration however depends on a few records which must exist in the database, otherwise it will fail. Inserting these records into the database is most definitely a test case by itself too. So my question is, should I execute my tests in a specific order in order for the records to exist, or should I explicitly insert the records again in every testcase that depends on it?

It might be somewhat irrelevant but I'm using Laravel 5, so testing is done in PHPUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I execute my tests in a specific order in order for the
>   records to exist, or should I explicitly insert the records again in
>   every testcase that depends on it?

I think the correct answer here is that you should not do either (but please  read on, it might still be ok to do the latter, though not perfect).

If you say registering the user is a test case in itself. Very well then, write that test and let's assume you have that test in what follows.

**Creating tests so that they run in order**

Lets deal with the first option of running the creating those rows once and then running multiple tests against them.
I think this is a very flawed approach no matter the circumstances. All of a sudden all tests depend on one another. 
Say you run test A, B and C on those rows. Maybe it's even the case that right now none of them alters the rows. But there is no way you can be sure that no bug is ever introduced into B that alters data ( mustn't even be a bug, could just be that the underlying functionality is changed ).
Now you're in a situation where test C might pass, but only if B did not run before. This is an entirely unacceptable situation, especially when the reverse is true, C only passing if B ran.
This could show in say a fresh installation of your App throwing errors in real life, while your development setup containing a bunch of data works and so do the tests because B created a certain state in your database ( that maybe also exists randomly in your dev database ).
Then you give it out to some poor customer and all of a sudden "option X" is not set, or the initial admin user does not exist or whatever :)
=> **bad plan**

**Running the Setup for Every Test that depends on it**

This is a significantly better plan. Now you at least have full control of your database state in every test and they all run independent of one another.
The order of them running will not affect outcome 
=> **good**

Also this is a relatively standard thing to do for a subset of tests. Just subclass your main UnittestCase class and make all tests depending on that function subclasses of that thing like so:

```
abstract class NeedsDbSetupTestCase extends MyAppMainTestCase {

  function setUp(){
     parent::setUp();
     $this->setupDb();
  }

  private function setupDb(){
    //add your rows and tables and such
  }
}
```

=> **acceptable idea**

**The Optimal Approach**

The above still comes some drawbacks. For one it isn't really a unittest anymore once it depends on very specific database interactions, which makes it less valueable in exactly pinpointing an issue. Admittedly though this is in many cases more a theoretical than a practical issue :)

What will much more likely become a practical issue though is performance. You are adding a bunch of database writes that might need to be run hundreds of times once your test suit grows. At the beginning of your project this might mean that it takes 4s to run it instead of 2s :P ... once the project grows you might find yourself losing a lot of time because of this though.

One last issues you might also face is that your test suit becomes dependent on the database it's run against. Maybe it passes running against MySQL 5.5 and fails against 5.6 ( academic example I guess :P ) => you might have all kinds of strange behavior with tests passing locally but failing in CI and whatnot (somewhat likely depending on your setup).

Since you are interesting in this in a more generic sense, let me outline the proper way of handling this here generically too :)

What it will always come down to is that a situation like this causes you trouble:

class User {
  private $id;

public function get_data(){
   return make_a_sql_call_and_return_row_as_array("SELECT properta1, propertyb FROM users WHERE id = " . $this->id);
  }

}

Now some other method is to be tested that actually uses the return of `get_data()` and you need that data in the db :) ... or you just mock your User object!

Assuming you have some method in another class that uses that User object.
And your test looks a little something like this:

```
// run this in the context of the class that sets up the db for you
$user = new User($user_id);
$this->assertTrue(some_method_or_function($user);
```

All you need here from $user is to say return the array [1,5]. Instead of inserting this and then using an instance of User, just create the mock:

```
// this one doesn't do anything yet, returns null on every method.
$user = $this->getMockBuilder('User')->disableOriginalConstructor()->get_mock();
// now just make it return what you want it to return
$user->method('get_data')->willReturn(array(1,2));
// And run your test lightning fast without having ever touched the database but getting the same result :)
$this->assertTrue(some_method_or_function($user);
```

Another hidden ( but valuable ) benefit of this approach is, that setting up the mocks and such actually forces you about the details that go into every classes behavior, giving you a significantly more detailed understanding of your app in the end.
Obviously the downside is that it (not always but often) requires a lot more work to code your tests this way and the benefit might not be worth the trouble.
Especially when working with other frameworks like WordPress and such that your code depends on, it might be somewhat unfeasible to really mock all db interaction, while existing libraries provide slower but trivial to implement database testing capabilities for your code :)

But in general option 3 is the way to go, option one is just wrong and option two might be what everyone eventually does in real life :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! Always glad to see some real-world examples. I think I'll stick with option 2 for now since it kind of relates directly to running a migration command (easy peasy in laravel) to populate my database, but I'll be sure to try out mocking and see how that works for me. +1